# Sencha Touch: SASS correct image path

Tags: extjs, sass, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have problems with adding (background-) images via SASS. If I open my app on the sencha web server the images that are referenced in CSS (or SASS) can be found and are visible. But in the production build of my app the same images can't be found. It's because after the build, the images are being moved into a different location in the resources/ folder.

So I want to ask, what is the correct way in SASS for referencing images? How can I fix my problem?

---

The debug version:

- images are in folder ./resources/images
- in ./resources/sass/app.scss there is a line with "background-image: url('../images/pic.png')"

The build version:

- images are now in folder **./resources/resources/images**
- the references in the CSS/SASS are now invalid!

Comment: Why there is a difference in path for debug and build versions

Comment: That's one of the things I also don't understand why.

In my app.json there is this line:

"resources": [
        "resources/images",
        "resources/icons",
        "resources/startup",
        "resources/fonts"
    ].

Maybe there is a problem with it?

Comment: could you run "sencha app refresh" once, delete the old build and run everything again. Probably the images are not copied by default and you did move them.